# why import is not working

Tags: javascript, babeljs, cloud9

I'm using cloud 9 for my react/angular project. I successfully initialized `npm` and installed some packages and I wanted to install `react-inline-edit`.
I did it but when I was about to use it `import InlineEdit from 'react-edit-inline'`everything goes broken.
Also until now I never required or imported anything. Here's my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-merge-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel reactSource -d reactDirective -w -s"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "react-edit-inline": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-edit-inline": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

and my config.js file:

```
import InlineEdit from 'react-edit-inline';
var FormattedDate = ReactIntl.FormattedDate;
var DiaryTable = React.createClass({displayName: "DiaryTable",
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items : this.props.item,
            globalChecked:false
        };
    },
    handleAddElement(element) {
        if(this.state.globalChecked)
        {
            element.selected = this.state.globalChecked;
        }
        this.state.items.push(element);
        this.setState(this.state.items);
    },
    handleEditElement(element,index){
        if(this.state.items[index].selected)
        {
            element.selected = this.state.items[index].selected;
        }
        this.state.items[index] = element;
        this.setState(this.state.items);
    },
    handleChecked : function (i) {
        this.state.items[i].selected =  !this.state.items[i].selected;
        this.setState(this.state.items);
    },
    checkAll:function () {
        console.log(this.state.items);
        this.state.globalChecked = !this.state.globalChecked;
        this.setState({globalChecked:this.state.globalChecked});
        var ifChecked = this.state.globalChecked;
        this.state.items = this.state.items.map(function(element) {
            return { start: element.start,end:element.end,hours:element.hours,selected: ifChecked };
        });
        this.setState({items:this.state.items});
    },
    remove : function () {
        for(var i = 0;i<this.state.items.length;i++)
        {
            if(this.state.items[i].selected)
            {
               this.state.items.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        this.setState(this.state.items);
    },
    setResult:function () {
        this.state.items.length = 0;
        if(this.state.globalChecked)
        {
            for(var i=0;i<this.props.result.item.length;i++){
                this.state.items[i] = {start:this.props.result.item[i].start,end:this.props.result.item[i].end,hours:this.props.result.item[i].hours,selected:true};
            }
            this.setState(this.state.items);
        }
        else {
            for(var i=0;i<this.props.result.item.length;i++){
                this.state.items[i] = {start:this.props.result.item[i].start,end:this.props.result.item[i].end,hours:this.props.result.item[i].hours};
            }
            this.setState(this.state.items);
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        var arrayItems =  this.state.items.map(function (item,i) {
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"  checked={item.selected} onClick={this.handleChecked.bind(this,i)}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.start}/></td>
                    <td><FormattedDate value={item.end}/></td>
                    <td>{Number(item.hours)}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ModalEditElement items={this.state.items} onEditElement={this.handleEditElement} index={i} checked={this.state.globalChecked} ></ModalEditElement>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        }.bind(this));
        return (
            <table className="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onClick={this.checkAll}/></th>
                    <th>Start Date:</th>
                    <th>End Date:</th>
                    <th id="hoursField">Hours:</th>
                    <th id="editField">Edit:</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {arrayItems}
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="4">
                        <span className="addButtonDisplay"><ModalAddElement onAddElement={this.handleAddElement} items={this.state.items} checked={this.state.globalChecked}></ModalAddElement></span>
                        <button className="myButton" onClick={this.remove}>Remove period</button>
                        <button className="myButton" disabled={this.props.result.item.length === 0} onClick={this.setResult}>Set result from merge</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        );
    }
 });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Merging Arrays</title>

    <!--css styles start-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width:1171px)" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:1171px)" href="css/anotherStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.datepick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond.datepick.css">
    <!--css styles end-->

    <!--js resources start-->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngReact.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-intl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jQueryValidationMethods.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messageValidationOverride.js"></script>
    <script src="reactDirective/diaryComponent.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <!--js resources end-->
</head>
```

I'm trying to import it into my `config.js` file not in my `index.html` (that is correct right?). The thing is that until now everything I have, like external files, is in my project and I'm linking it in standard way `<script src="..."> </script>`.
In the example I'm following they are also importing React from React but I have it already linked in the way I mentioned (`<script></script>`).

The console says that require IS NOT DEFINED.

maybe I should import Boostrap,Angular,React and everything Im using like this import in order to work react-inline-edit ??But I don't see why they are already linked in my html ..
Can anyone help me import/require files or tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what does *everything goes broken* mean? Are you getting error messages? Can you share them?

Comment: It means that my react components are not rendered when I add 'import' in my .js file.In cloud 9 there's no proper console window for javascript files only the browser'one but because all my files are on the cloud there are a lot errors but one of them is : require is not defined .

Comment: where is the example you are following, can you link to it? Importing like that usually requires a library so you can import, its not native to javascript (but maybe babel should do it). Require is not defined means that the library that takes care of your imports isnt defined so cant import ( i think)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-edit-inline that's what I'm following

Comment: so it looks like you need to install `CommonJS` - this is the module loader that uses `import` and `require()`. or have you tried removing the `import` statement?